# How to display rows with same id but different row values?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to describe it in words so i'll show you:
[View scores table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgrUn.jpg)

I'm trying to display rows that has the same id, and display their values but in different tables. As seen in the picture, I have to make a table like that for every row that has the same ID. The main purpose of it is to compare their scores from before, when they first took the exams, to what the score they got now from the same set of exams.

This is what my database looks like right now. They have different scoreIDs and other row values but has the same id_applicant for it refers that these scores are of this certain applicant. [Database Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPSKd.jpg)

This is what my code for it looks like. (id_applicant is the one that they will have the same id)

```
<!-- VIEW SCORES -->
        <div style="background-color: #E9E9E9" class="tab-pane" id="ViewScoresTab">
            <div class="list-group">
                <div id="view-scores">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:20px">
                       <br>
                        <div id="inputhere"></div>
                            <h1><span class="label label-default">View Scores</span></h1>
                            <br><br>
                            <table>
                               <tr>
                                  <th bgcolor= '#00BFFF'>TEST</th>
                                  <th bgcolor= '#FFD700'>SCORES</th>
                                  <th bgcolor= '00FF00'>REMARKS</th>
                               </tr>
                       <?php
                            $servername = "localhost";
                            $username = "root";
                            $password = "";
                            $dbname = "offsourcing";

                            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                            // Check connection
                            if (!$conn) {
                                die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                            } 
                            if(isset($ids_holder)){
                            $q = "SELECT * FROM scores WHERE id_applicant = $ids_holder";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $q);
                            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                            for(int x=0;x!=rowcount;x++){
                              //some code for here
                            }

                                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                                    echo
                               "<tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Grammar </td>
                                  <td> $row[2]  </td>
                                  <td> $row[8] </td>
                               </tr>

                               <tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Customer Service </td>
                                  <td> $row[3] </td>
                                  <td> $row[9] </td>

                               <tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Logical Reasoning </td>
                                  <td> $row[4] </td>
                                  <td> $row[10] </td>
                               </tr>

                               <tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Idioms </td>
                                  <td> $row[5] </td>
                                  <td> $row[11] </td>
                               </tr>

                               <tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Call Listening (1) </td>
                                  <td> $row[6] </td>
                                  <td> $row[12] </td>
                               </tr>

                               <tr>
                                  <td class= 'test'> Call Listening (2) </td>
                                  <td> $row[7] </td>
                                  <td> $row[13] </td>
                               </tr>"; 
                               mysqli_close($conn);
                           } 
                       }
                               ?>
                            </table>
                            <br><br>  
                            <br><br>  
                            <br><br>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do it yet so any idea?

Comment: Supply a snippet of your table and columns and data, to give us a better picture please.

Comment: @Tommy you mean from my database, riht?

Comment: Yeah, like the table of data you're pulling from.

Comment: @Tommy I posted it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of targeting the number in the Array, directly target the column.
So replacing your while loop with something like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                           echo
                           '<tr>
                              <td class= 'test'> Grammar </td>
                              <td>'.$row['GrammarScore'].'</td>
                           </tr>

                           <tr>
                              <td class= 'test'> Customer Service </td>
                              <td>'.$row['CustomerServiceScore'].'</td>
                           </tr>'; //etc }
```

Is this what you mean? You said something about comparing the older scores to the newer ones, but you didn't really post anything about how you're calling these records, assuming they're on a different table?

Comment: Uhh I need to display them on different tables, not just in one. Just like the picture i posted of the View Scores, I need each of the rows that has that id_applicant to be displayed on that kind of table, each one will have each table like that.

Comment: So you need to create multiple tables, depending on how many applicants are passed through? What i posted, if you use the same query will create ONE table based on what ID is passed through on $q where you wrote id_applicant = $ids_holder, so only 1 will be created?